# timestamps into 10 minutes interval per row with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I have some data with `timestamp` in unix format, and I need to aggregate my data by 10 minutes: to find `ts_start` and `ts_end` where `timestamp` between `ts_start` and `ts_end`, and `ts_end - ts_start = 10 minutes`.

I am having difficulty finding functions in `pyspark.sql` to transform my timestamps and perform this aggregation. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance

I need to find `ts_start` and `ts_end`, not only aggregate

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need to find `ts_start` and `ts_end`? do these need to be stored in a separate column? what is your expected output?

Comment: Yes, as separated columns.

Comment: please share a sample input and its desired output for better reach and understanding